# modifying tokens generated through standard tokenizer

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-plugin

I was trying to understand the working of standard tokenizer. Below is the code inside my tokenizerFactory file:

```
package pl.allegro.tech.elasticsearch.index.analysis.pl;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Tokenizer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.env.Environment;
import org.elasticsearch.index.IndexSettings;
import org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AbstractTokenizerFactory;

public class UrlTokenizerFactory extends AbstractTokenizerFactory {

    public UrlTokenizerFactory(IndexSettings indexSettings, Environment environment, String name, Settings settings) {
        super(indexSettings, name, settings);
    }

    @Override
    public Tokenizer create() {
        StandardTokenizer t = new StandardTokenizer();
        return t;
    }
}
```

I want to modify each and every token generated through the standard tokenizer. For example, just to test that I can modify the tokens; I want to add an "a" or any other character at the end of every token. I tried to concatenate the "a" character at the end of the token in the return statement of the above create function using the "+" operator but it didn't worked. Anyone have any idea on how to implement this?

Comment: thanks for marking as solution. Please upvote as well if it really helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define [Pattern replace char filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html) with custom analyzer. this will add the `_a` with all the token generated and you not need to update it in Java code.

```json
POST _analyze
{
  "text": [
    "Stack overflow"
  ],
  "tokenizer": "standard", 
  "char_filter": [
    {
      "type": "pattern_replace",
      "pattern": "(\\S+)",
      "replacement": "$0_a"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output:**

```json
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "Stack_a",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "overflow_a",
      "start_offset" : 6,
      "end_offset" : 14,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```